# Dimension of a function

Tags: r, function, dimensions

Because this would simplify my code only slightly, I'm mainly asking out of curiosity. Say you have a function

```
f <- function(x) {
  c(x[1] - x[2],
    x[2] - x[3],
    x[3] - x[1])
}
```

Is there a way of finding out the dimension of the input required, e.g.

```
dim(f) = 3
```

Comment: I would argue that a function has no dimension. Arrays can have one. And why should your function have dim 3? Depending on the input the output vector  could be every integer.

Comment: It is not clear why would we need this. Maybe input validation inside the function, do not run if length is not 3, etc.

Comment: @Alex Wouldn't this function throw an error if I would only input something 2dim?

Comment: @zx8754 Say you have a lot of different functions like the one above all having different input needs, and now you want to make sure that you choose the right input for each function.

Comment: What can you subset with `x[i]`. Only vectors?

Comment: Yes, this function is basically the right-hand side of a differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very questionable solution that involves [computing on the language](https://www.google.ca/search?q=r+"computing+on+the+language").

I've written three functions that allow matching, searching, and extracting pieces of parse trees based on a sort of "template" parse tree piece. Here they are:

```
ptlike <- function(lhs,rhs,wcs='.any.',wcf=NULL) if (is.symbol(rhs) && as.character(rhs)%in%wcs) !is.function(wcf) || isTRUE(wcf(lhs,as.character(rhs))) else typeof(lhs) == typeof(rhs) && length(lhs) == length(rhs) && if (is.call(lhs)) all(sapply(seq_along(lhs),function(i) ptlike(lhs[[i]],rhs[[i]],wcs,wcf))) else lhs == rhs;
ptfind <- function(ptspace,ptpat,wcs='.any.',wcf=NULL,locf=NULL,loc=integer(),ptspaceorig=ptspace) c(list(),if (ptlike(ptspace,ptpat,wcs,wcf) && (!is.function(locf) || isTRUE(locf(ptspaceorig,loc)))) list(loc),if (is.call(ptspace)) do.call(c,lapply(seq_along(ptspace),function(i) ptfind(ptspace[[i]],ptpat,wcs,wcf,locf,c(loc,i),ptspaceorig))));
ptextract <- function(ptspace,ptpat,gets='.get.',wcs='.any.',wcf=NULL,locf=NULL,getf=NULL) { getlocs <- do.call(c,lapply(gets,function(get) ptfind(ptpat,as.symbol(get),character()))); if (length(getlocs)==0L) getlocs <- list(integer()); c(list(),do.call(c,lapply(ptfind(ptspace,ptpat,unique(c(gets,wcs)),wcf,locf),function(loc) do.call(c,lapply(getlocs,function(getloc) { cloc <- c(loc,getloc); ptget <- if (length(cloc)>0) ptspace[[cloc]] else ptspace; if (!is.function(getf) || isTRUE(getf(if (missing(ptget)) substitute() else ptget,loc,getloc,as.character(ptpat[[getloc]])))) list(if (missing(ptget)) substitute() else ptget); }))))); };
```

`ptlike()` matches two parse tree pieces against each other, allowing for wildcards on the RHS to match anything. For example:

```
ptlike(1L,2L);
## [1] FALSE
ptlike(1L,1L);
## [1] TRUE
ptlike(quote(a),quote(b));
## [1] FALSE
ptlike(quote(a),quote(a));
## [1] TRUE
ptlike(quote(sum(a+1)),quote(sum(b+1)));
## [1] FALSE
ptlike(quote(sum(a+1)),quote(sum(.any.+1)));
## [1] TRUE
ptlike(quote(sum(a+1)),quote(.any.(a+1)));
## [1] TRUE
ptlike(quote(sum(a+1)),quote(.any.));
## [1] TRUE
```

`ptfind()` returns a recursive index vector for each match of a parse tree pattern (RHS, if you like) in a given parse tree space (LHS), combined into a list. For example:

```
sp <- quote({ a+b*c:d; e+f*g:h; });
ptfind(sp,quote(.any.:.any.));
## [[1]]
## [1] 2 3 3
##
## [[2]]
## [1] 3 3 3
##
sp[[c(2L,3L,3L)]];
## c:d
sp[[c(3L,3L,3L)]];
## g:h
```

`ptextract()` is similar to `ptfind()`, but returns the matched piece of the parse tree space or a subset thereof:

```
ptextract(sp,quote(c:d));
## [[1]]
## c:d
##
ptextract(sp,quote(.any.:.any.));
## [[1]]
## c:d
##
## [[2]]
## g:h
##
ptextract(sp,quote(.any.:.get.));
## [[1]]
## d
##
## [[2]]
## h
##
```

---

So what we can do is extract from (the parse tree that comprises the body of) your function all the subscripts of the `x` argument and get the maximum literal subscript value:

```
f <- function(x) c(x[1L]-x[2L],x[2L]-x[3L],x[3L]-x[1L]);
max(unlist(Filter(is.numeric,ptextract(body(f),quote(x[.get.])))));
## [1] 3
```

The `Filter(is.numeric,...)` piece isn't really necessary here, since all subscripts are literal numbers (doubles in your definition, integers in mine, although that's inconsequential), but if there were ever non-numeric-literal subscripts, then it would be necessary.

Caveats:

- It's absurd.
- It would not take into account variable subscripts that might rise above the maximum literal subscript value in the parse tree. (Although, strictly speaking, in the general case, it is *impossible* to statically analyze all possible subscripts that might occur at run-time, due to the halting problem or something.)
- If the vector was ever assigned to a different variable name, say `y`, and then *that* variable was indexed with a different subscript, even a numeric literal subscript, this algorithm would not take that into account.
- And there's probably some more.